# ajaxSetup, between postbacks, MVC Project

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have this function

```
SetAjaxDefaults: function () {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                type: 'GET',
                headers: General.Headers(),
                error: function (data) {
                    var textLog = '';
                    if (data && data.responseJSON) {
                        textLog = data.responseJSON.Message;
                    } else if (data && data.statusText) {
                        textLog = data.statusText;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

I call it in my login page, hoping all my future pages will be affected by this setup, but after some tests I relized that I have to set the defaults for each ***View*** or at least for each ***Layout***

Is there a way to set the defaults for the entire site? it would be easy I guess if it were a SPA Framework but it is ASPnet MVC.

Comment: put this in the layout.

Comment: @Fran, thanks but if you _read my question_ it says it works on the Layout, I am looking for a more general solution if possible

Comment: how many layouts do you have in the site?

Comment: and there's is no sitewide setting because javascript loads on a per page basis.  if you are in a SPA there's only one page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MVC setup includes a shared layout file in Views -> Shared and is called _Layout.cshtml

If you put scripts in here they will be available to all view which use the shared layout.

The layout usually just loads a bundled set of scripts. this is set up in the file in App_Start -> Bundle_Config.cs

If you save your script in a separate file and add it to the bundle, this should be loaded in ALL your layout files.

Comment: This is not what I was looking for, however it is a smart solution and I think good enough